# Tensor Product of Vector with Itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\vec x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.
If I wanted to compute a linear map

$$\vec x\mapsto A\vec x,$$

it would suffice to compute it on $n$ unit vectors $u_i  = A\vec e_i$.
From these $n$ elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$, one can recover the value of $A\vec x$ for any $\vec x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Moreover, if I wanted to compute this linear map for $x\in V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\dim V = k$, it would suffice to compute it on any $k$-dimensional basis of this subspace, i.e. from $k$ elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$ one can recover the value of $A\vec x$ for any $\vec x\in V$.

I am curious about the generalization of this to the map

$$\vec x\mapsto A'(\vec x\otimes \vec x)$$

where $A'\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n^2}$.
Ideally, this would be computable from $o(n^2)$ elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$, i.e. the span of the set

$$V' = \{\vec x\otimes \vec x\mid \vec x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$$

would be contained in a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ of dimension $o(n^2)$.
Is this true?
In general, is there a way to "compress" the map $\vec x\mapsto A'(\vec x\otimes \vec x)$ to $o(mn^2)$ real elements, by leveraging that we are only interested in its action on structured elements of the form $\vec x\otimes \vec x$ for $\vec x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, rather than arbitrary elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$?

Comment: For example, if you're not going to consider the entire tensor product (whose elements are sums of decomposable tensors), how can $A'(e_i\otimes e_i)$, $i=1,\dots,n$, give you the values of all $A'(x\otimes x)$?

Comment: @Mark The dimension of the span of this set of vectors is in general $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} > n^2/2$, which is notably not $o(n^2)$.

Comment: By the way, you are totally misusing the notation: $V^{\otimes 2}$ is standardly just another notation for the complete tensor product $V\otimes V$.

Comment: The span of $\{x\otimes x\mid x\in\Bbb R^n\}$ is the subspace of *symmetric* tensors, with basis $\{e_i\otimes e_j+e_i\otimes e_j\mid i\le j\}$ of cardinality $(\!(\begin{smallmatrix}n\\2\end{smallmatrix})\!)=\binom{n+1}{2}$.

Comment: @Mark The more common notation for the subspace that you are considering is $V \vee V$, or $V^{\vee 2}$

Comment: Thanks for the references! I'd be happy accepting either statement that $\dim (V\wedge V) > n^2/2$ as an answer. This (somewhat trivial) question has led to a further question, but I'll probably ask it elsewhere and perhaps link it here.